# Install Microsoft WebDevServer?

Tags: .net, web-development-server, asp.net-development-serv, aspnet-development-server

At some point, I accidentally uninstalled the development server used to run and test my project's website on my machine.  I have tried repairing all instances of visual studio I have installed, as well as repairing all version of .Net Frameworks that i have installed. None have restored the exe I need.  (Program Files/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/DevServer/10.0/WebDev.WebServer40.exe)  Anyone know what I should be doing to fix this?

Comment: you can try installing cassini webserver from external link. Actually the webdev server we use is cassini too.

Comment: The problem is that I am on a team and the solution is set up to use visual studio's native development server. I don't have the authority or desire to change the entire team's development server because I did something stupid on my machine.  I just need to figure out how to reinstall the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, somehow the executable has returned - not sure exactly what brought it back, but it has returned.  Most likely, what brought it back was outright re-installing visual studio 2010 and 2012.